# Simulation getting terminated abruptly

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am getting the below mentioned message and my code terminates execution.

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information. terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc

What is the reason behind it? Well my simulation contains close to a 100,000 nodes. Is it because of that? I am using omnetpp-4.6 on windows 7.

---

**EDIT:** after trying lower number of nodes

I tried changing the number of nodes but still got the below message :

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information. terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cRuntimeError' what(): Attempt to delete network during simulation.

So I guess this is also running out of memory

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` means that no Memory can be reserved. You probably ran out of Memory.

Comment: But I did not have any memory leak in the code. Then is it solely because the size of the simulation ?

Comment: simply try it with 10,000 nodes and see if the problem occurs. If yes decrease the number to 1,000.

Comment: @Sampi I don't know how one node Looks like but 100,000 is a pretty high number. Especially if they contain additional data structures. For simulations of such high amounts it is often a good idea to use Memory efficient data structures. Right now Adjacency Matrices come into my mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix. If it the amount of nodes is really the Problem, you can probably try to use a different data structure.

Comment: I tried changing the number of nodes but still got the below message :    This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
     Please contact the application's support team for more information.
     terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cRuntimeError'
     what():  Attempt to delete network during simulation.  So I guess this is also running out of memory.

Comment: no I am only deleting messages.